# sqlite3 db file roll over after reaching a size

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 in a C++ application. There are multiple instances of the application accessing the same DB. The DB file size grows infinite till the disk gets filled. Hence am trying out a mechanism to roll over the sqlite3 DB file to new file when it reaches a specific size. Say am using file "db1.sql". When it reaches the size 1000 KB, I want to rename "db1.sql" as "db2.sql" and continue writing to a new file "db1.sql". sqlit3_open API will create the file if it does not exist. When "db1.sql" again reaches 1000 KB i want to overwrite "db2.sql" and continue writing to new file "db1.sql" and so on. The threshold size 1000 KB is configurable. The complex part is many applications are using the same DB file. Hence when I do this rename and open/create new file, it should not effect other application. The name of active DB file should be always "db1.sql". What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Lock the database when copying.  "The complex part is many applications are using the same DB file" - then Sqlite seems to be a poor choice. MySql would have been better suited.

Comment: Why can't you delete old data from the database?